# use UIAlertView when camera is running in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uialertview, avcapturesession

I'm trying to trigger an AlertView when my camera detect a face using OpenCV. I manage to do the face detection and can output an NSLog successfully. But when I tried to trigger the alert view with

```
NSLog(@"Face Detected");
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Face Detected" message:@"Do you really  want to try again?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];

[alert show];
[alert release];
```

I can see the Alert View is kind of triggered as the screen is dimmed but I could never see the alert view came out...

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

Remove `[alert release]`. You already called `autorelease` on it.

Also, you can integrate `[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];` in the initializer:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Face Detected" 
                                                message:@"Do you really  want to try again?" 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: I think the memory problem is actually what causes the error. The alert view is released too early and can not be displayed.

Comment: I tried fabian789's code but again it showed a dimmed screen like the alertview is called, but with no pop-up...

Answer (score 1):

where are you calling this from ? Main thread or secondary ?
Because UIKit stuff should always been done on main thread.

Code example:

```
- (void)opencvFaceDetect
{
  // stuff before
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(openAlertView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];
  // stuff after
}
```

and then

```
- (void)openAlertView
{
  UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Face Detected" 
                                                message:@"Do you really  want to try again?" 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I try to call the Alert view in a void called opencvFaceDetect. How can I call the alert view not from main thread?

Comment: would the problem be with the buffer frames constantly being showed to the screen so that I cant see the Alert View?

Comment: if your opencvFaceDetect method as been called by a method not in the main thread for example. to be sure, use the NSObject's method  performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

Comment: the frames being drawn can't be the problem because you can see the dimming effect.

Comment: but I think the real issue is the one fabian789 is pointing: releasing too soon.

Comment: I modified the code with the correct released. I now triggered the Alert View in a void openAlertView method and I now added this in opencvFaceDetect:
 
[self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(openAlertView); withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false];

I got an unrecognized error though, can someone try to show me an example about how to do this?

Comment: the screen is still dimming ?

Comment: you have a ';' just after the '@selector(openAlertView)'